# Woocommerce choose grid or list view for each category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want the possibility to choose between grid and list view for each Woocommerce category. I have found this plugin: https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-grid-list-toggle/

However, the plugin is meant for the shopper to choose whether to display items in grid view or list view. What I truly want is the ability to assign a view for each category in the back-end.

Example:

Category A is displayed as grid
Category B is displayed as list

Breaking my head over this.

Comment: Not crazy different from http://stackoverflow.com/a/33622302/383847. just slightly different conditional logic. If you want to be able to set the display style in the admin you will need to add term meta. WooCommerce has functions for this and it is coming into WordPress core in 4.4.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thank you for the answer. That code is nog working for me but would be great to. I have an category named Nussmylch and only want the list view for this category.

Comment: it always helps to specify exactly what isn't working about something. That helps others get to the bottom of things faster than the generic (and much dreaded) "it isn't working" :) I took another crack at it, see my answer below.

Comment: @helgatheviking I have added the code from below to the functions.php and did what you said. It is not working later i added it to woocommerce.php and added an new category named test But there is one problem. In my theme options you have the option to choose how much products you want to show on youre product category pages. You have the theme folder and then an folder called functions with an php file called woocommerce. It looks like this: 
http://christiaangrob.nl/VOORBEELD.txt

Comment: Let's move this discussion to the answer in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33622302/383847) you need to filter [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include). You need to call your custom archive template `archive-list-view.php` and save it in your theme's `woocommerce` folder. Obviously, you can name it anything you like, you will just have to adjust the code below to match.

Folder structure:

```
/theme-folder/functions.php
/theme-folder/woocommerce/archive-list-view.php
```

On the `template_include` filter we will check if we are on the term archive for the `nussmylch` product category. If so, we'll look for and supply the new template. Otherwise, the standard template is used.

**EDIT**: incorrect WooCommerce function [`is_product_taxonomy()`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_product_taxonomy.html) was used. [`is_product_category()`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_product_category.html) is needed to check for a specific category.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'so_33615903_custom_category_template', 20 );

function so_33615903_custom_category_template( $template ) {
    // check you are on the taxonomy archive for specific category
    if ( is_product_category( 'nussmylch' )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'woocommerce/archive-list-view.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            $template = $new_template ;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

[Working Example](https://wordpress-helgatheviking.c9.io/product-category/testing/)

Comment: @robin If we're discussing this answer, let's do so here. Why is any of this "But there is one problem. In my theme options you have the option to choose how much products you want to show on youre product category pages. You have the theme folder and then an folder called functions with an php file called woocommerce. " a problem? Also by "not working" I assume you mean you aren't getting a different template when viewing the test category?

Comment: The above code goes in your theme's root `functions.php` file. Though arguably it shouldn't make a difference. Have you created a `woocommerce/archive-list-view.php` template? If the code can't find a template, it will use the default. Do you have the correct category slug?

Comment: This works but one thing left, when I change the <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?> to <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'productlist' ); ?> in the woocommerce/archive-list-view.php there are no products in the category.  In the Woocommerce folder I have added the content-productlist.php it looks like the file can not be found. The products are not displayed

Comment: Are you sure you have products in that category? IE. can you echo something else out in the while loop, like a word or a simple counter? `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     <?php echo 'bacon'; wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>` If you are seeing the `wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' )` template then that confirms you have no products in that category.

Comment: The code inside the woocommerce/archive-list-view.php is the code from the Woocommere plugin: woocommerce/archive-product.php the original Woocommerce product archive.

Comment: I've figured it out! recplace the line <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>  with <?php woocommerce_get_template( '../woocommerce/templates/content-productlist.php' ); ?>

Comment: `wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'productlist' ); ` works for me assuming that your file is name `woocommerce/content-productlist.php`.