# 2 Layouts for a WooCommerce shop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have to categories named "Collectie" and "Shop", what I want is different layouts for the children of both categories.

I already tried this with the template_include function like this:

```
function lab5_template_include( $template ) {
    if ( category_has_children('collectie')) {
        $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/archive-product-collectie.php';
    }elseif ( is_product_category('shop')) {
        $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/archive-product-shop.php';
    } 
    return $template;
}
```

How do I do that?

**EDIT**

I solved it with the solution from https://wordpress.org/support/topic/different-page-layouts-for-category-vs-subcategory

i added the next lines to taxonomy-product_cat.php

```
// We need to get the top-level category so we know which template to load.
$get_cat = $wp_query->query['product_cat'];

// Split
$all_the_cats = explode('/', $get_cat);

// How many categories are there?
$cat_count = count($all_the_cats);

//
// All the cats say meow!
//

// Define the parent
$parent_cat = $all_the_cats[0];

// Collectie
if ( $parent_cat == 'collectie' ) woocommerce_get_template( 'archive-product-collectie.php' );

// Shop
elseif ( $parent_cat == 'shop' ) woocommerce_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off running a `while` loop to determine the parent level category name. Then you can match it against the different parent categories you want to display differently.

**edit** `lab5_template_include()` should use `is_product_category()` instead of `is_product_taxonomy()` which returns true on product category *and* tag archives.

```
function lab5_template_include( $template ) {

    if( is_product_category()){ 

        $slug = get_query_var('product_cat');

        $cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $slug, 'product_cat' ); 

        $catParent = so_top_product_category_slug($cat);

        // locate the new templates
        if ( 'collectie' == $catParent ) {
            $new_template = locate_template( array( 'woocommerce/archive-product-collectie.php' ) );
        } elseif ( 'shop' == $catParent ) ) {
            $new_template = locate_template( array( 'woocommerce/archive-product-shop.php' ) );
        } 

        // set the new template if found
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            $template = $new_template ;
        }

    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'lab5_template_include', 20 );
```

**edit** bug fixes and improved efficiency of `so_top_product_category_slug()`. Now tested and working.

```
// get the top-level parent product category from a term object or term slug
function so_top_product_category_slug($cat) {
    if( is_object( $cat ) ){
        $catid = $cat->term_id;
    } else {
        $cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $cat, 'product_cat' );
        $catid = $cat->term_id;
    }
    $parentId = $cat->parent;
    $parentSlug = $cat->slug;
    while ($parentId > 0) {
        $cat = get_term_by( 'id', $parentId, 'product_cat' );
        $parentId = $cat->parent; // assign parent ID (if exists) to $catid
        $parentSlug = $cat->slug;
    }
    return $parentSlug;
}
```

Comment: Thanks helga, i will try it and get back to it!

Comment: FYI- i've updated to use `locate_template`. I think that should help. Though I haven't tested the `so_top_product_category_slug()` function, it is adapted from another function I know works, so I have high hopes for it. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help helga, i solved it with the solution from https://wordpress.org/support/topic/different-page-layouts-for-category-vs-subcategory

Comment: 1. did you try my solution? did it not work? 2. you should post the solution here so you can accept it as an answer though the linked support thread isn't even related to filtering `template_include`. That's borderline a completely different question.

Comment: Hi Helga, the solution above did not work, i do appreciate your help. The link i posted in the comment fits my need to use different layout for the "Collectie" and "Shop" categories.

Comment: Ok, while I still think that the link doesn't even represent the same question you asked, for SO purposes you should post a complete answer (not a link in a comment or original question) and eventually accept it as the answer. For anyone coming along later, the solution I've posted is now tested and working.